# Calc formula to determine Remembrance Sunday

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have a perpetual calendar and have just about figured out special dates...  except for the first Sunday on or after (in this case) Nov 11th.

I could do something like:
DATE(calendarYear,6,1+7*2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(calendarYear,11,8-1))
for the 2nd Sunday in November, but in 2019, for example, it's on the 3rd Sunday.

Any ideas?

Comment: "2019, for example, it's on the 3rd Sunday." No it's not. "Sun Nov 10 2019 Remembrance Sunday" (https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/uk/remembrance-sunday). That is the **2nd** Sunday.

Comment: It's always on the 2nd Sunday in November.